# MS Access, how to replace a saved query by the full query in a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:
1 - tblMembers_Info
2 - a junction table
3 - tblCourses

I need to query the members who haven't done a specific course.

After trying to do it manually I gave MS Access "Query Wizard" a try. I ended up with :

A saved query as Query1:
// That one query who did the course

```
SELECT tblMembers_Info.*, tblCourses.CourseName
FROM tblMembers_Info 
INNER JOIN 
(tblCourses INNER JOIN tblMembers_Courses 
  ON tblCourses.IDCourses = tblMembers_Courses.IDCourses)
ON tblMembers_Info.Members_ID = tblMembers_Courses.Members_ID
WHERE (tblCourses.CourseName) In ('NameOftheCourse');
```

2nd query using the saved Query1:

```
SELECT tblMembers_Info.Members_ID, tblMembers_Info.FirstName, tblMembers_Info.LastName 
FROM tblMembers_Info 
    LEFT JOIN [Query1] 
      ON tblMembers_Info.[Members_ID] = Query1.[Members_ID] 
WHERE (((Query1.Members_ID) Is Null));
```

How can I replace the Query1 in the second query with the full query instead of using a QueryDef (the saved query "Query1")?

Also, there's a better way for sure to write that query, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply replace `LEFT JOIN [Query1]` with `LEFT JOIN (...) AS [Query1]` where `...` should be the SQL of the first query, without the ending `;`.

But I think in your specific case the use of `NOT IN` might give a better performance to get the same results:

```
SELECT     tblMembers_Info.Members_ID, tblMembers_Info.FirstName, tblMembers_Info.LastName 
FROM       tblMembers_Info 
WHERE      tblMembers_Info.[Members_ID] NOT IN (
    SELECT     tblMembers_Info.[Members_ID]
    FROM       ((tblMembers_Info 
    INNER JOIN tblMembers_Courses
            ON tblMembers_Info.Members_ID = tblMembers_Courses.Members_ID)
    INNER JOIN tblCourses
            ON tblCourses.IDCourses = tblMembers_Courses.IDCourses)
    WHERE      tblCourses.CourseName = 'NameOftheCourse'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried the "NOT IN" before but I might have done something wrong when I tried it since I was getting all the members instead of only the one I wanted. I don't have the query that I tried here but I cannot wait to double check what was different from the one you gave me.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. It might be that you tried `NOT IN` with a subquery that selected more than one column.